# How to scan Bluetooth BR/EDR (Classic) with Python on macOS?

Tags: python, macos, bluetooth

I'm developing a remote sensor using ESP32 to collect data and send it to my macOS via Bluetooth, and use Python to receive it from the macOS side. I hope I can build a small Python tool to:

1. Scan surrounding Bluetooth devices.
2. User selects the specific one they want (in this way, my ESP32 Bluetooth device).
3. Create communication between them.

I know the vanilla Python can communicate with MAC address of a connected Bluetooth device (STEP 3), according to [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8pMaR-WUc6U). But the problem is how can I find the MAC address programmatically (STEP 1).

1. Since `PyBluez` is not under development anymore, it's not considered.
2. `bleak` can only discover BLE devices, according to [its documentation](https://bleak.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/scanner.html). Also, I tried to scan with it, but the output only shows the name as `None` for BR/EDR (Classic) devices. (I replace the real address with x for privacy reason):

```
xxxxxxxx-2C6A-65F5-9450-xxxxxxxxxxxx: None
xxxxxxxx-D159-3E92-85BF-xxxxxxxxxxxx: None
xxxxxxxx-1206-C3AF-4A51-xxxxxxxxxxxx: Yiming’s iPhone
```